# django-rest-framework: Unknown command: 'generateschema'

Tags: django-rest-framework

Executed the command according to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#quickstart):

```
python.exe manage.py generateschema > schema.yml
```

But instead of YAML got an error:

> Unknown command: 'generateschema'
>
> Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Package versions:

- Django 2.1
- PyYAML 3.13
- coreapi 2.3.3
- djangorestframework 3.8.2

Comment: Could be a wrong setting file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check, if such command exists, using `python manage.py help`. The output you expect is

```
[rest_framework]
    generateschema
```

If you don't have such command, then try to reinstall drf

Comment: Thanks! `generateschema` appeared in help menu now but I'm still having problems with YAML https://shrib.com/?v=nc#gLwSqF-GYyr4BH6EPUXX

Comment: @Symon - honestly, I can't help you with that. Better ask new question

Answer (score 6):

Add `'rest_framework'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rest_framework',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`generateschema` is a new command from `djangorestframework`.

*I had the same issue, and just needed to upgrade it*

```
pip install djangorestframework --upgrade
```