# How to import swagger/?format=openapi to postman from django-rest-swagger without error of format not recognized

Tags: django, swagger

Our project use django-rest-swagger to manage API, and we would like to export all api and import `Postman`, I can get JSON by below url `localhost:5000/swagger/?format=openapi`, but when I import the file, postman says `Error while importing: format not recognized`, How to import swagger/?format=openapi to postman from django-rest-swagger without error of format not recognized?

Is there anyone who knows some easy way to solve it? Thanks so much for any advice!!!!!

```
{
swagger: "2.0",
info: {
title: "TestProjectAPI",
description: "",
version: ""
},
host: "localhost:5000",
schemes: [
"http"
],
paths: {
/api-token/: {
post: {
operationId: "api-token_post",
responses: {
201: {
description: ""
}
},
parameters: [
{
name: "data",
in: "body",
schema: {
type: "object",
properties: {
pic_id: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
phonenumber: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
checkcode: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
user_phone: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
phone_code: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
username: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
password: {
description: "",
type: "string"
}
}
}
}
],
description: "User Login",
summary: "User Login",
consumes: [
"application/json"
],
tags: [
"api-token"
]
}
},
/porject_management/: {
get: {
operationId: "porject_management_list",
responses: {
200: {
description: ""
}
},
parameters: [
{
name: "page",
required: false,
in: "query",
description: "A page number within the paginated result set.",
type: "integer"
},
{
name: "page_size",
required: false,
in: "query",
description: "Number of results to return per page.",
type: "integer"
},
{
name: "search",
required: false,
in: "query",
description: "A search term.",
type: "string"
},
{
name: "project",
required: false,
in: "query",
description: "",
type: "string"
},
{
name: "state",
required: false,
in: "query",
description: "",
type: "number"
},
{
name: "ordering",
required: false,
in: "query",
description: "Which field to use when ordering the results.",
type: "string"
}
],
description: "porject management",
summary: "porject management",
tags: [
"porject_management_post"
]
},
post: {
operationId: "porject_management_post",
responses: {
201: {
description: ""
}
},
parameters: [
{
name: "data",
in: "body",
schema: {
type: "object",
properties: {
project: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
tc_code: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
visitors_number: {
description: "",
type: "integer"
},
site_selection: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
contact_name: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
contact_number: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
remark: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
type: {
description: "",
type: "integer"
},
state: {
description: "",
type: "integer"
},
status: {
description: "",
type: "integer"
},
creater: {
description: "",
type: "string"
},
modifier: {
description: "",
type: "string"
}
}
}
}
],
description: "Porject management",
summary: "Porject management",
consumes: [
"application/json"
],
tags: [
"homemanager"
]
}
},
securityDefinitions: {
basic: {
type: "basic"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem by eolink.com,

Firstly, import JSON from `localhost:5000/swagger/?format=openapi`

Secondly, export Swagger by eolink.com, and then you can import that file to postman!!!

Comment: Depending on your configuration it also can be `localhost:5000/?format=openapi` (for anyone in the future reading this)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```
python3 manage.py generateschema --file openapi-schema.yml
```

in terminal? Then you can directly import the schema to your POSTMAN. You are providing JSON format, use yaml format for postman it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work, I got error of `manage.py generateschema: error: unrecognized arguments: --file openapi-schema.yml`

Comment: I found a similar question and a accepted answer for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54750464/7775998

Comment: Finally, I solved my problem by eolink.com